# Showing fragment in ViewPager overlapped

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with 2 fragments, it uses a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Now it shows only one fragment at a time, I would like to show the fragments a bit overlapped, like in this [link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1N73wlMermJbyW9yK5g-MF0PusxUGCOOoryNXpDeHT8Y/edit?usp=sharing).

Is it possible to do this without changing structure? In other words, without using MultiPaneLayout or something like that?

Thanks everyone